# Basic array formula only working in first cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge data sheet of tons of repeats of names (Column F Sheet 1) with a column of dates (Column C Sheet 1) of when they ordered. I want to find the minimum and maximum dates of the orders to find out when the customer first ordered and last ordered. This formula works only for the first row.

=MIN(IF(Sheet1!$F:$F=$A2,dates))
=MAX(IF(names=$A2,dates))

This is calculated on sheet 2 which has a list of unique names in the A column.

(they are two variations of the same thing to see if one worked when dragging down but both do work on the first row)

I'm on mac and people have suggested control + U and then cmd + return but this just skews up all the formula. I've also tried blank cells etc. I can't see anything wrong with the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365 you can take advantage of [MAXIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MAXIFS-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883) function:

=MAXIFS(Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet1!$F:$F,"="&A2)

For older excel versions, you have to use an Array Formula. Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER will convert the formula in an Array Formula:

=MAX(IF(Sheet1!$F:$F=A2,Sheet1!$C:$C))

=MIN(IF(Sheet1!$F:$F=A2,Sheet1!$C:$C))

Comment: don't have office 365 unfortunately, the mac equivalent is control+u cmd+return but it still only works for the first line. I have 15000 rows with many duplicates of the names in the first data set is this too much to handle or what? I'm so unsure why it isn't working

Comment: Have you dragged the formula to the other cells?

Comment: yeah just displays 0 on everything else, is there anyway i can share it with you to show you?

Comment: @LiamCook You can edit your question to see where you've got